# Using pandas to clean massive dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So kinda a newb here, but I have this dataset that is transposed wkardly, I want to have this back to our guy in the next week, and I've gotten pretty close to completing - I think.

The problem I am facing is getting the data into one data frame. When I run the code, and print from the for loop, I can see the chunks of values that will need to be concatenated. however, i cant find a way to store all the values. when I do, I just get one chunk.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np


 df = pd.read_excel("DATA,h",
 header = None,
 dtype = object)

 ranges = []
 last_index = 0 


def clean(df12,df13):
    df12 = df12.T
    df13 = df13.T
    value1 = pd.DataFrame(df12)
    value2 = pd.DataFrame(df13)
    final_value = value1.append(value2)
return(final_value)


for i, row in df.iterrows():
    rows = df.iloc[i]
    if rows[9] == 'Member' or rows[9] == 'Non-Pledging Member':
        if last_index == 0:
            last_index = i
        else:
            ranges.append([last_index, i])
            last_index = i
        df44 = beans(row,row)

print(df44)
```

when I print rows from the for loop I get all the values I need in the terminal, but if i store it in a value or dataframe.. I just see one of those blocks of data. Does anyone know whats going on?

data: there are 15k of these

```
Proctor, Terry      206-915-3555                    Member  
620 33rd Ave E                                  16283
Seattle, WA 98112
```

what I am shooting for:

```
 Proctor, Terry, 620 33rd Ave E, Seattle, WA, 98112, 206-915-3555, Member
```

Comment: Can you post what the dataset looks like and what the expected output is supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry, just did!

Comment: The original datasets also are needed.